# How to fetch phpbb3 fourm name and description in my wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, phpbb3

I have a wordpress blog that is integrated with phpbb3.I want to show a listing of `php bb3 forum` in my wordpress blog index page.
But i am not able to find any help.please help me if anybody.I shall be very thankful to you.
On my `wordpress index page` it only showing title of `phpbb3`fourm title but i need description also.

I am using this function to display `forum topics` in my wordpress blog

**file:custom-function.php**

```
    function widget_wpulatestphpbbtopics_custom($args)
         {
     if(!is_admin())
     {      
          //extract($args);
          $options = get_option('widget_wpulatestphpbbtopics');
         $title = $options['title'];
       //$maxEntries = $options['max'];
        //generate the widget output
        // wpu_template_funcs.php MUST be available!
if ( !function_exists('wpu_latest_phpbb_topics')) return false;
echo $before_widget;
echo"<h1>";echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;echo"</h1>";
echo '<ul class="wpulatesttopics">';
wpu_latest_phpbb_topics('limit='.$maxEntries);
echo '</ul>' . $after_widget;
}
}
       function limit_front_page()
         {
global $query_string;
if (is_home())
{
query_posts($query_string.'meta_key=featured_image');
widget_wpulatestphpbbtopics_custom($args);
}
     }
   add_action('thesis_hook_before_content', 'limit_front_page');
```

Answer (score 0):

With the widget you're using it doesn't look like the $options array will ever return anything other than title or max posts.  I think you'll need to update your widget to pull the FORUM_DESC value as well, or write a DB call to pull this directly from the database